# Trouble with receiving messages for chat program

Tags: c, sockets, gtk, glade, gtk#

I am working on a chat program in C using c socket programming and gtk+ for the GUI.
I have 2 variations of the program running on 2 separate computers, 1 variation has client-side code and the other has server-side code, both have the same GUI and same user functionality options.

My program works when the client is a GUI and the server is running without a GUI but, when I try enabling the GUI for the server, the client-side can still connect to the server but messages don't seem to go through for some reason.

I used glade which is a software to easily create the GUI so the syntax is a bit different than gtk but it uses gtk so it should be the same.
the main function for my server GUI looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //GtkBuilder      *builder;
    GtkWidget       *window;

    //creating a widgets from type app_widgets
    app_widgets     *widgets = g_slice_new(app_widgets);
    //GtkTextIter iter;

    //creating gtk_init
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    printf("creating gtk_init successfully");

    //using gtk_builder to create the graphics for the gui using glade
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("glade/window_main.glade");

    //binding the builder to the main container
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));


    // Get pointers to widgets
    //pointer to the main text view where chat is shown
    widgets->w_txtvw_main = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "txtview_main"));
    //pointer to main text buffer that displays the chat
    widgets->textbuffer_main = GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "textbuffer_main"));
    //pointer to text buffer where user can type msgs for server
    widgets->textbuffer_type = GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "textbuffer_type"));


    //connecting the widgets to signal to the builder
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, widgets);

    //gtk_widget_show is called once done setting up widget settings
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    //start client side
    //connecting to sock
    sock = startServer();
    printf("sock: %d", sock);
    if(sock < 0) {
        printf("PROGRAM ERROR: Client did not launch!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    int valListen = listenToSock(sock);
    printf("valListen: %d\n", valListen);
    if(valListen == -1) {
        printf("PROGRAM ERROR: Server failed listening to socket");
        printf("Please Relaunch the Application!");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("sock: %d", sock);
/*
    //validating key generation
    int valKey = getKey(keyP);
    //once password was entered successfully, check will be changed to 1
    int check = 0;

    if(valKey < 0) {
        printf("PROGRAM ERROR: password hashed did not hash successfully");
        exit(0);
    }
*/


    //currReceive is the status of the received data, if equal to 1 than data received,
    int currReceive = 0;

    //bufOutput is the data received
    char bufOutput[] = "";
    //pointer to bufOutput
    char  * bOP = bufOutput;

    //using a while loop for gtk_main_iteration
    //using gtk_main_iteration() instead of gtk_main() because i need to receive msgs while gui works - need to handle a few events
    while (1==1) {
        //runs 1 iteration of main loop
        gtk_main_iteration();

        //checking if received data
        currReceive = receive(bOP, sock, key, valQ);

        //currReceive = 1 if data was received
        if(currReceive == 1) {
            //printing msg in cmd
            printf("\nMessage: %s<\n", bOP);

            //updating the main buffer for viewing chat with the new msg received
            update_main_viewedit(widgets, bOP, "Server: ");
        }
        //if receiving failed, quit
        if(currReceive == -1) {
            printf("PROGRAM ERROR: Receiving from server failed");
            on_window_main_destroy();
            return -1;
        }
    }


    //free widgets memory
    g_slice_free(app_widgets, widgets);

    return 0;
}
```

The receive function works properly as I have tested it outside of the GUI and also run a simple function to test both the receive and send functions and they work seamlessly:
the simple function looks like this:

```
void communicateUsingFunctions(int sock) {


        int valid;
        char info[MAX];
        char * send = info;
        while(1 == 1) {
                valid = receive(send, sock, 3, 0);
                if(valid == 1) {
                        printf("Message From Functions: %s", send);
                        sendToClient(send, sock, "dsad");
                }
        }
}
```

I would love for some help, as I don't know why it's not working, both receive and send functions work properly with the other side's GUI.

Thanks to anyone that contributes!

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be trying to combine your own hand-rolled `while (TRUE)` loop instead of the event loop (aka GMainLoop) that GTK is using, by calling `gtk_main_iteration()`. Note also that the documentation even explicitly mentions this is a blocking call:

> If no events are waiting to be processed GTK will block until the next event is noticed.

People trying to do funky stuff like this is really why `gtk_main*()` are removed from GTK4 (in favor of just using `GtkApplication`). So this:

```
//using gtk_main_iteration() instead of gtk_main() because i need to receive msgs while gui works - need to handle a few events
```

isn't really a good way of having to run stuff concurrently.

On how to actually solve this: there are a number of ways to call asynchronous code in GLib so that you don't block the main thread (where the UI runs), which is actually nicely integrated into the main loop as well. See for example:

- [`GIOStream`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GIOStream.html) (and its several subclasses)
- [`GSocket`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSocket.html)
- [`GSource`](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/custom-gsource.c.html.en) (if you really want to go lower level and integrate a custom main loop, but it seems to be overkill for your use case)